# How to implements Progress bar when doing Ajax request Voluminous db updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, activerecord, progress-bar

Good morning,
I have script that updates voluminous data (for exemple 3000Lines) and I have to show to user progress of db updates on progress bar or just the number of lines affected.
I'm working on PHP codeigniter and AJAX
I had an idea to use session codeigniter to store modified variable (incrementation) on the session value on each Loop and call function that give me the session variable as JSON array, but the problem is that the session wouldn't change itself after first update (for exemple: starting with 0 and modified to 20, after that all process on 20)

I don't know how to get better solution to do it. If you can help me it will be really cool.
Thank's to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP won't output anything until the script has fully completed, but you can change that:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Put this in your PHP script before you start processing your data. As you process parts of your data, output something to tell the AJAX request the progress; for example:

PHP:

```
$completed_updates = 0;
$last_echoed_progress = 0;
$progress_echo_interval_seconds = 2;
while ($completed_updates < $amount_of_db_updates_to_do) {
    do_db_update();
    $completed_updates++;
    if ($last_echoed_progress + $progress_echo_interval_seconds < time()) {
        echo ($completed_updates / $amount_of_db_updates_to_do) * 100;
        $last_echoed_progress = time();
    }
}
```

jQuery's .ajax also (by default) won't call the success function with the data until all the data has been received (i.e. script ended), so create a custom XHR object with an event listener that receives the data while the script is still running:

JS:

```
var last_response_length = 0;
$.ajax({
    ... // All your other settings
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create a custom XHR object

        xhr.onprogress = function(data) {
            var response = data.currentTarget.response, // Get the output
                progress = response.slice(last_response_length) | 0; // Remove old output

            $( '#progress-bar' ).val(progress); // Update the progress bar
            last_response_length = response.length; // Track where the old data is (so they can be removed when new data is received)
        };
        return xhr; // IMPORTANT! Return the custom XHR for .ajax to use
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $( '#progress-bar' ).val(100); // All done!
    }
});
```

Obviously modify the code to suit your needs, and experiment a little. Keep in mind that PHP has an execution time limit of 30 seconds by default, so you may need to change this inside your script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This allows your script (and only that one) to run without time limits. Put it at the very top. Use caution!

Comment: I will try it And tell you if it's Ok, thank you very much

Comment: It seems Works thanks, but little problem:
When it change for example 44 to 45 , many times it shows 4445 and after 45 (erased) 47 etc.. i think problem with speed of execution.
Any idéa to resolve this?

Comment: @NeoFethiCh Hmm interesting... I will look a little bit more in depth later but for now you could try `echo`ing outside the `for` loop in your PHP, outputting the progress at intervals rather than on every iteration (e.g. `while (true) { if ($last_echo + 2 < time()) echo $progress; $last_echo = time() }`). It could be a JS problem though...

Comment: @NeoFethiCh I have updated the code so that the progress is only outputted in timed intervals.

Comment: It's Seems Working! PERFECT !
Thank you very much